# Remove validation from element in Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

I have jquery validation(With twitter bootstrap) on my page and I use the following ASP.NET MVC annotation.

```
[DisplayName("Text)"),Range(100,35000)]
    public decimal Field { get; set; }
```

The element is added with:

```
@Bootstrap.TextBoxFor(x => x.Field, htmlAttributes: new {@class="ignore",id="field" })
```

The problem is that I want to allow an empty value in this field but keep the range validation in case a non empty value in written.

This is my javascript code:

```
$("#Field").on("keyup", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($(this).val() == "") {
            $(this).removeClass("input-validation-error");
            $(this).addClass("valid");
            $(this).next().html("");
            $(this).parent().parent().removeClass("error");
        }
    })

    $.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: ".ignore" });
```

Comment: **Quote**: _"I want to allow an empty value in this field but keep the range validation in case a non empty value is written"_ ~ To validate an input element but not make it `required` simply means removing the `required` rule while keeping the `range` rule.

Comment: Also, why are you creating a `keyup` function to do a whole bunch of things the plugin is already doing or capable of doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution...If you make the type nullable it works...

```
[DisplayName("Text)"),Range(100,35000)]
public decimal? Field { get; set; }
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score -2):

I post you an hack on 'required' validation.
The idea is to return the opposite of required true if field is empty, or else return true if value is out for range. maybe you'll need to personalize the default required message too, for UX's sake

```
$("form").validate({
rules: {
    field1: {
        required: function() {
        return (
                                $("#fld1").val() != "" || 
                                ($("#fld1").val() != "" &&
                                (
                                 $("#fld1").val() < minVal  ||
                                 $("#fld1").val() > maxVal
                                ))
                     );
        }
    }
},....
```

Comment: Why are you writing a whole new function for a rule that already exists in the plugin?

Comment: Actually there's not a validation function that checks on a range only if the value isn't null.

Comment: [No, actually there is a rule called `range`](http://jsfiddle.net/tLG9v/).  And all the Validate Plugin rules still work fine even when `required` is not `true`.  [See:  http://jsfiddle.net/tLG9v/](http://jsfiddle.net/tLG9v/)